# tabbed UWP app codedui assertion tab content is reloaded

Tags: c#, uwp, coded-ui-tests

I have a UWP app with tabs and I'm doing an action on one of the tabs (i.e: save) and I want to wait until the tab is refreshed.

My question is: If I used appwindow.WaitForControlReady() is this a correct indication? or does appwindow is always available so this won't work correctly?
anyway what will appwindow.WaitForControlReady() do in my case?

```
 //app main window
 XamlWindow mainWindow = new XamlWindow();
 mainWindow.SearchProperties[XamlControl.PropertyNames.ClassName] = "Windows.UI.Core.CoreWindow";
 //Console.WriteLine("name= {0}", mainWindow.GetProperty("Name"));

 //TabPage
 XamlControl tabPage = new XamlControl(mainWindow);
 tabPage.SearchProperties[UITestControl.PropertyNames.ControlType] = "TabPage";
 tabPage.SearchProperties[UITestControl.PropertyNames.Name] = "Xamarin.Forms.NavigationPage";
 tabPage.SearchProperties["Instance"] = tabNumber;

 //enter material
 XamlEdit materialID = new XamlEdit(tabPage);
 materialID.SearchProperties[XamlEdit.PropertyNames.Name] = "Material Description";
 UITestControlCollection test = materialID.FindMatchingControls();
 materialID.Text = Material;
 //click on filter button
 Mouse.Click(GetButton(ButtonEnum.Filter, manageMaterialTabPage));
 // wait for lists to be refreshed
 mainWindow.WaitForControlReady();
```

After clicking Filter button I want to assert on the lists that they were filtered by material (refreshed). so will mainWindow.WaitForControlReady() do the trick?

Comment: We cannot answer your question without much more detail of your application. There are several `WaitFor ...` methods , perhaps `WaitForControlExists` would be more suitable. Please [edit] the question to add details of the structure etc of the relevant part of the application.

Comment: @AdrianHHH Done. thank you for the tips.

Comment: It's not clear to me if you want to a) check if the list is effectively filtered b) check if the list was refreshed.

"b" doesn't rule out "a" has happened and "a" doesn't rule out "b" has happened. So those are 2 separate things you could/should check.

Comment: Yes, I want to wait for the list to be refreshed.. the checking on "effectively filtered" I've already did it

Comment: I think it _should_ work. You could test this by doing a action on your list that is only valid if the list is truly refreshed.